# Molecular diffusion into sphere

Tags: chemical-engineering

The gas $(A)$ is diffusing into the solid sphere $(B)$, The sphere phase is assumed to be stagnant so we have no bulk movement, $(A)$ is being consumed in the sphere by a rate of $KC_A$ which $K$ is a kinetic constant and $C_A$ is concentration of $A$ in the sphere, $C_A$ in sphere as a function of $r$ (radius) is desired.

By the species continuity Eqn. we have :

$\frac{1}{r^2} \frac{d}{dr}(r^2N_A)=-KC_A$

By definition of $N_A$ we have:

$N_A=y_AN_t-D_{AB}\frac{dC_A}{dr}$

which $N_t$ is zero by the stagnant assumption. By substituting $N_A$ in the first Equation and differentiating we obtain:

$C_A''+\frac{2}{r}C_A'-\frac{K}{D_{AB}}C_A$=0

I just don't know how to solve this differential equation, maybe there's a need for a simplifier assumption that I didn't make, anyway I welcome any advice from you guys helping me find the answer.

Comment: try laplace transforms?

Comment: @user2539738 It requires boundary conditions to solve, which I don't have at the time.

Comment: Why dont you try to solve it numerically using finite difference method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ODE is: $$c''+\frac 2r c'-\frac KDc=0.$$

Assuming $r\neq 0$, use the substitution $c = \frac {f(r)}{r}$. After substitution you will obtain $f''-\frac KD f=0$. This ODE can be solved by hyperbolic sine and hyperbolic cosine functions or simple exponential functions.